# Returning SOAPFault from JAX-WS Provider<SOAPMessage>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, websphere-7

what is the preferred way of creating SOAPMessage containing a SOAPFault from a webservice that implements JAX-WS Provider interface?

`MessageFactory.newInstance()` seems like unnecessarily expensive operation and there's no mention about thread safety. I have four possible solutions, but got no idea which I should be using:

1. Pool of MessageFactories in a static variable
2. Reuse the received
3. SOAPMessage by clearing the content and possible attachment Create a synchronized method for `MessageFactory.createMessage()`
4. Use `MessageFactory.newInstance()` for every call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil

As this will be very easy to change later, I would go with option 4 (`MessageFactory.newInstance()` every time) and only consider other options if and when I see it has performance issues.

This might not be a performance issue at all and you'll save yourself some coding.

Comment: I agree that premature optimization is bad, but the service (= webservice proxy that resides at network edge) is required to process thousands of messages per second. After exploring the source codes, benchmarking & profiling I decided to use pooling